# Event of radiobuttunList which defined in userControl

Tags: jquery, radiobuttonlist

I want to write change() for radiobuttunList.
My radio button is in user Control.
So I am writing jquery function in main page.

Can any one help me?

```
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Wizard1_ucCustomers_PackageInfo_ddlPackage").val();
```

by using above code I am getting only 1st value of radiobuttonList.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input:radio[name=nameofcheckbox]:checked').val();
```

This will get you the selected value off the checkbox